How to build If condition comparing metadata output against a variable containing multiple values
sorry newbie here.
I have a variable ('small_list') with default value [ 'A', 'B', 'D'].  I have a Get Metadata that will get foldernames from a container (A,B,C,D,E,F).  Using a ForEach to loop round these foldernames I need to check if foldername is in the variable 'small_list' (A,B & D) and if it is do activity and if not in the 'small_list' do different activity, so C,E & F do fail condition.
enter image description here
